# Dedup logic without getting "cannot return value referencing local variable `queues` returns a value referencing data owned by the current function"

Tags: rust

I have the following structs:

```
use std::sync::Mutex;

pub struct Message {
    id: String,
    content: String,
    last_read: Option<String>,
    uuid: String,
}

impl Message {
    pub fn get_uuid(&self) -> String {
        self.uuid.to_owned()
    }
}

pub struct Queue {
    queue: Vec<Message>, // the actual queue
    read_timeout: u32,   // the amount of time a message is hidden from consumers
    size: u32,           // should always be the same as queue.len()
    uuid: String,
}

pub struct AppState {
    pub queues: Mutex<Vec<Queue>>,
}
```

Finally, I have some functions that do something with the data. They have duplicate logic, as you can see below. What they do after they get the `queue` is different, but the way to retrieve the queue is the same.

```
pub async fn add_message(
    data: AppState
) {
    let queue_uuid = &String::from("my uuid");
    
    let queue_mutex = data.queues.lock();
    let mut queues = match queue_mutex {
        Ok(q) => q,
        Err(_) => return,
    };
    // find matching queue 
    let queue = queues.iter_mut().find(|q| q.uuid == *queue_uuid);
}

pub async fn get_message(
    data: AppState
) {
    let queue_uuid = &String::from("my uuid");
    
    let queue_mutex = data.queues.lock();
    let mut queues = match queue_mutex {
        Ok(q) => q,
        Err(_) => return,
    };
    // find matching queue 
    let queue = queues.iter_mut().find(|q| q.uuid == *queue_uuid);
    // once the queue is found, do some stuff with it 
}
```

I would like to dedup this logic.

```
impl AppState {
    pub fn get_queues(&self) -> &Mutex<Vec<Queue>> {
        &self.queues
    }

    pub fn get_queue_by_id(&mut self, uuid: String) -> Result<&mut Queue, String> {
        let queue_mutex = self.queues.lock();
        let mut queues = match queue_mutex {
            Ok(q) => q,
            Err(_) => return Err(String::from("Whoops! Something went wrong")),
        };
        match queues.iter_mut().find(|q| q.uuid == uuid) {
            None => Err(format!("Could not find queue with uuid {}", uuid)),
            Some(q) => Ok(q),
        }
    }
}
```

However, this will yield an error because I cannot return `q` as it will be dropped when the function returns. Is there a good solution to this?

P.S: I know that a lot of this could be more efficient - i.e. using a hash map instead of vector to store the current queues. I am a Rust newbie and intend on refactoring a lot of this, so any feedback is helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Note: in async contexts blocking like `std::sync::Mutex::lock` requires is not the best idea, use an asynchronous variant like `futures::lock::Mutex` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to being more appropriate in `async` contexts than `std::sync::Mutex` anyways the `futures` variant has another benefit, it allows your usage pattern by having a [`MutexGuard::map`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.28/futures/lock/struct.MutexGuard.html#method.map) which let's you return a `MappedMutexGuard<Vec<Queue>, Queue>`:

```rust
impl AppState {
    pub async fn get_queue_by_id(
        &mut self,
        uuid: String,
    ) -> Result<MappedMutexGuard<Vec<Queue>, Queue>, String> {
        let mut queues = self.queues.lock().await;
        match queues.iter_mut().position(|q| q.uuid == uuid) {
            None => Err(format!("Could not find queue with uuid {}", uuid)),
            Some(p) => Ok(MutexGuard::map(queues, |q| &mut q[p])),
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I know the same is not (yet?) possible with the `Mutex` in `std`, see [this Rust internals discussion](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/add-map-methods-for-mutexguard/18081).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return just a mutex's contents, you can return `impl DerefMut<Target = _>`. This will allow you to swap out the synchronization wrapper you use without changing the function's signature.

```rs
pub fn queues(&self) -> Result<impl Deref<Target = Vec<Queue>> + '_, String> {
    self.queues.lock().map_err(|_| "Mutex poisoned".to_string())
}

// The same since `Mutex` doesn't differentiate between readers and writers. However,
// if a `RwLock` is used instead, this would be different from `queues`.
pub fn queues_mut(&self) -> Result<impl DerefMut<Target = Vec<Queue>> + '_, String> {
    self.queues.lock().map_err(|_| "Mutex poisoned".to_string())
}
```

This doesn't work for getting a specific queue, but the other answer explains how you can do this with the future crate's mutex.

One way to do this with the std mutex is to take a closure that modifies the selected queue.

```rs
pub fn modify_queue_by_id<F, R>(&mut self, uuid: String, f: F) -> Result<R, String>
where
    F: FnOnce(&mut Queue) -> R,
{
    let mut queues = self
        .queues
        .lock()
        .map_err(|_| "Whoops! Something went wrong".to_string())?;

    let queue = queues
        .iter_mut()
        .find(|q| q.uuid == uuid)
        .ok_or_else(|| format!("Could not find queue with uuid {}", uuid))?;

    Ok(f(queue))
}
```

Since this takes a regular `FnOnce` closure and not a `Future`, this ensures that the lock isn't held across an `await`, even in a single-threaded runtime context.